# Characteristic of the following field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, characteristics

I have $2$ similar questions :

1. Is  the following set $K$ a field: 
   $$K=\underset{i=even}{\bigcup} \mathbb{F}_{2^{i}}$$ where $\mathbb{F}_{2^{i}}$  values are all finite fields?

Is so, what is the characteristic of this field?

2. Is $K \cup \mathbb{F}_{2^{3}}$ a field?

My answer is: yes both $1$ and $2$ are infinite fields by subfield criterion of finite fields, but I am not sure!

And what about the characteristic? Is it $2,$ which is the base prime, or is it $0,$ since it is infinite?

Comment: Maybe make clear first what is your background knowledge on field theory and finite field.

Comment: I may be splitting hairs, but ... The accepted answer is good, but before we get there I want to make sure you understand the formation of this union. We can form unions of number fields easily because we think of them as specific subsets of $\Bbb{C}$ or $\Bbb{R}$. Depending on how the finite fields were constructed in your course, forming the union in the first place has a few subtleties. Yes, we can sweep them under the rug by assuming an algebraical closure, and working inside that. But without that universal wrapper around it is not immediate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I believe that in the course the field is constructed  by assuming algebraic closure.  But could you please explain how does it make diffrence by assuming subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?  Assuming a universal wrapper, do you also think that, it is not trivial to solve the problem? What would your answer to be? I will remove the accepted mark in case different opinions come for this question. It seems it needs more detailed analysis. Do you think that  $K\cup F_{2^3}$ will be equal to something else if the universal wrapper changes?

Comment: esra, do keep the accepted answer! Particularly if you had already settled the the existence of an algebraic closure. My concern is about how the form the union of, say $\Bbb{F}_4=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ and $\Bbb{F}_{16}=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x+1)$ and the rest of them. Without that wrapper provided by the algebraic closure it is a bit subtle. For example because there are two ways of identifying $\Bbb{F}_4$ as a subset of $\Bbb{F}_{16}$, and that problem branches out and propagates along the union. But disappears, if you work inside an algebraic closure.

Comment: I said I am splitting hairs :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok then, I will keep the accepted answer. But I think you were right, that was an important point actually. But now having to know that it is algebraic closure, I am more confident of the solution provided. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Agreed. Without algebraic closure around, it is not clear for example how to form the sum of an element of $\Bbb{F}_{16}$ and $\Bbb{F}_{64}$. GreginGre gets around that problem by first identifying both as subfields of $\Bbb{F}_{4096}$. Which is a fine way of doing that, but does depend on the choice of identifications. The problem in my mind is analogous to that of identifying $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ with a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$. Do you map the coset of $x$ to $\sqrt2$ or to $-\sqrt2$?

Comment: Makes no difference unless you want use the arithmetic of $\Bbb{R}$ to compute the sum of the image of $x$ and $\sqrt3$. Such problems can be dealt with. And the process is kinda standard (Zorn's lemma kind of thing).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see what you mean, without the algebraic closure there is not a unique identification of the subfields, it just depends  on the irreducible polynomial we choose to identify the field, and there are more than one irreducible polynomials we can determine it.  But with algebraic closure it is not a problem, since every polynomial splits completely over  the algebraic closure. So can we say that we identify  the fields $F_{2^i}$'s as subfields of algebraic closure of $F_{2}$ and then it becomes trivial to prove the stability of both + and . operations?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you say: "Such problems can be dealt with. And the process is kinda standard (Zorn's lemma kind of thing" Assuming for a while that we do not use the algebraic closure as the main structure, and we do not use $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ exc. In other words each field has it's own identification which is not clear to us. How can we prove that K is a field? Or can we? By saying those problems can be dealt with, do mean that we can still prove that it is a field? even in that case?

Comment: May be not exactly Zorn's lemma :-/. One way to get to the algebraic closure would be to specify, for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots$, an inclusion $\sigma_k:\Bbb{F}_{2^{k!}}\to\Bbb{F}_{2^{(k+1)!}}.$ This gives us a nested chain of inclusions
$$\Bbb{F}_2\subset\Bbb{F}_{2^2}\subset\Bbb{F}_{2^6}\subset\Bbb{F}_{2^{24}}\subset\Bbb{F}_{2^{120}}\subset\ldots.$$ Then we can form the union of that nested chain as a direct limit, and define operations there. We get all the finite extensions of the prime field, because any integer is a factor of some of the factorials.

Comment: To do something similar with the union of  all $\Bbb{F}_{2^i}$, $i$ an even natural number, we need a more complicated [directed system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) As long as we construct the inclusions carefully (so that "inclusion becomes associative"), it should work out the same :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the help. This is a nice/smart idea:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $K$ is a field, but this is not as trivial as it looks. The non trivial point is 
to show stablility by $+$.

Let $x\in\mathbb{F}_{2^i}$ and $y\in\mathbb{F}_{2^j}$.

Then $i\mid ij$ and $j\mid ij$, so $\mathbb{F}_{2^i}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2^j} $ are both contained in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{ij}}$, and $x+y\in \mathbb{F}_{2^{ij}}\subset K$ (since $ij$ is also even).

The characteristic of  $K$ is also equal to the characteristic of any subfield, since the unit elements are the same. Since $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a subfield, the characteristic of $K$ is $2$.

Since $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}\subset \mathbb{F}_{2^6}$, your field in Question 2. is just $K$....

Comment: Thanks for the perfect insight. But you say it is not as trivial as it seems because of the stability of +? But isn't it obvious from yhe subfield criteration theorem? If i|j then  $F_ {2^i} $ is a subfield of $F_ {2^j} $?  Union of fields is a field? Why do i need to take elements and prove the stability of +?

Comment: @esra In general, union of fields is not a field; for example $F_{2^2} \cup F_{2^3}$ is not a field. That is why it is nontrivial to show that this particular union you have gives a field.

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense. Thanks!