# Is $K = \bigcup\limits_{i:\text{even}} \mathbb{F_{2^i}}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

1. Is $K = \bigcup\limits_{i:\text{even}} \mathbb{F_{2^i}}$ a field?
2. If so what is char(K)?
3. Is $K \cup \mathbb{F_{2^8}}$ a field?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Exactly this question was asked on this site less than two weeks ago.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494263/characteristic-of-the-following-field) is the identical question from 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

For any prime $p$  and any positive integers $i,j$,
$\;\mathbf F_{p^i}\subseteq \mathbf F_{p^j}\;$ if and only if $i\mid j$.

So you essentially have to show the sum and product of two elements of $K$ are well-defined, even  if they live in different $\mathbf F_{p^i}$ and $\mathbf F_{p^j}.$ For this, observe that both fields are contained in $\mathbf F_{p^{\operatorname{lcm}(i,j)}}$.

As to the characteristic question, note that all these fields contain $\mathbf F_p$.